# Closures: I need to create a function called lightSwitch with a variable initially set to false, then have another function that inverts the value

Tags: javascript, closures

Write a function called lightSwitch. It will return an inner function.
Create a variable inside lightSwitch called isTheLightOn and set its initial value to the boolean false.
Write a function called flipTheSwitch inside lightSwitch.
The function should invert the value of isTheLightOn and return a string.
If the light is on (true), the string should be 'The light is on'
And if the light is off (false), the string should be 'The light is off'.
The lightSwitch function should return flipTheSwitch.

```js
function lightSwitch() {
  const isTheLightOn = false
  function flipTheSwitch(){
    if(!isTheLightOn  === false)
      return 'The light is on'
  } 
  {
    if(isTheLightOn === false)
      return 'the light is off'
  }
  return flipTheSwitch
}
```

I have written this so far and am unsure whats wrong with it:

Comment: Shouldn't that `if(isTheLightOn === false)` bit belong inside the inner function? Otherwise you've got a dangling anonymous block that doesn't seem to do anything. It's also not inverting the value.

Comment: There's what @David has mentioned and also `isTheLightOn` needs to be declared with `let` so that you can change it, and you need to change the value of `isTheLightOn` in the inner function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working example with the changes listed above in the comments, namely

1. `const` has been changed to `let` to allow the value to be changed.
2. The second block has been moved inside the inner function and changed to just an `else`, since booleans only have two options and another if is unnecessary (and slower).
3. We invert `isTheLightOn` inside the inner function by setting it to its inverse.

```js
function lightSwitch() {
  let isTheLightOn = false
  function flipTheSwitch(){
    isTheLightOn = !isTheLightOn;
    if(isTheLightOn)
      return 'The light is on'
    else
      return 'the light is off'
  } 
  
  return flipTheSwitch;
}

let light = lightSwitch();
console.log(light());
console.log(light());
```